# Integrating Copyleaks SDK with Angular

Tags: html, angular, plagiarism-detection, copyleaks-api

I am trying to integrate the Copyleaks SDK with Angular to be able to check for plagiarism on two text area fields in an HTML form. On the HTML form, I am trying to integrate two buttons, which checks for plagiarism on one text area field, and the other button to check for plagiarism on the other text area field.

I have looked at the NodeJS documentation for the Copyleaks SDK here to see if this would help:
https://github.com/Copyleaks/NodeJS-Plagiarism-Checker

However, the documentation seems unclear as how to use this, as it only gives an example in Javascript, which is shown in the index.js file. I am trying to use typescript for the plagiarism checking in my HTML form, as I am using the Angular framework.

Are there any other resources, or any other documentation that can help me with how to integrate Copyleaks with Angular to be able to check for plagiarism on two text area fields in an HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not recommended for integrating your client with Copyleaks servers. Instead, it is recommended to create a dedicated server that acts as an intermediary between your client and the Copyleaks server.